# Discord Bot JSON Parse Error

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.io

I should caveat this by stating that:

1. I have no experience with js but do have some experience with other languages
2. I did try to figure this out on my own before coming here.

I am essentially just trying to get the bot setup, and was attempting to install the bot dependencies when this occurred:

```
D:\>cd\Discord Bots\Ark FTW

D:\Discord Bots\Ark FTW>npm install discord.io winston-save
npm ERR! file D:\Discord Bots\Ark FTW\package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 3 while parsing near '{
npm ERR! “name”: “Ark FTW”,
npm ERR! ...'
npm ERR! File: D:\Discord Bots\Ark FTW\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\temp5\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-28T18_14_53_243Z-debug.log
```

I used a block of code from a tutorial just to get the bot setup, but I have no clue what syntax error I am looking for despite trying to figure it out for the last two hours.  I assume it something that will be obvious to anyone with a crumb of experience, but that is not me.

This is the JSON file in it's entirety:

```json
{
  “name”: “Ark FTW”,
  “version”: “1.0.0”,
  “description”: “I wanna be a real bot!”,
  “main”: “bot.js”,
  “author”: “Soldiercide”,
  “dependencies”: {}
}
```

I'm sorry for what is probably a stupid question, and I appreciate any direction you folks might be willing to provide.

Comment: The quotes look odd to me, if that is a direct copy they shouldn't be converted to the left and right Unicode quotes, just use the plain jane "

Comment: I'm with @RichardHubley. I would highly recommend just removing your `package.json` and then use `npm init`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quote characters you are using are not valid. [`“`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201C) and [`”`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+201D) and [`"`](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0022) are different characters. You should be using the last one.